# Do minotaurs from Dragonlance eat human flesh?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, food-and-drink, dragonlance, minotaur

Do minotaurs from Dragonlance eat human flesh? I am interested in running one from that setting who ended up in a different realm (through Spelljammer shenanigans) and I was wondering what their views on consuming the flesh of humanoids would be.

Answer (score 7):

Minotaurs in Dragonlance do not normally consume human flesh. In fact, due to their views on honor, they'd likely find the practice repulsive.

[This](http://www.dlnexus.com/features/articles/14636.aspx) is a link you may find useful. It outlines [Richard Knaak's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_A._Knaak) take on the subject, which states his view that they are omnivores with a tendency towards meat, favoring goat.

But it's your game, and SpellJammer gonna SpellJammer.